# can't find where BlackBerry 10 simulator was installed on MacOS, and re-install got "multiple launches of installer not allowed" error

Tags: blackberry-simulator, blackberry-10

Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5(11G63)

installer-bbndk-bb10_1_x-macosx-338-201302012246-201302032157.dmg
BlackBerry10Simulator-Installer-BB10_1_X-338-Mac-201302031817.dmg

After install the upper two dmg files, I can find qde in the launchpad, but I can not find the "BlackBerry10Simulator-BB10_n_nn.vmwarevm" file".

I want to re-install ,so I run the app "BlackBerry10Simulator-Installer.app" in Finder->devices->BlackBerry10Simulator-BB10-1-x, just get the pop-up-box saying

> **The Installer cannot be run.**
>
> **Multiple launches of this installer is not allowed. It will now quit**

, and then the installer quit.

How can I find the simulator install path,  or

**How can I re-Install it successfully**.

P.S.
At the first time installing, I did not change anything while installing, just clicked those "next","accept..." buttons.
I think the simulator should be installed in default file path, but I don't know where is it, and can't find it even searching "BlackBerry10Simulator" in Finder.

Maybe there is something wrong while first time installing simulator?

Answer (score 2):

The BB10 simulators are VMware virtual machines.  On a Mac, you need to have [VMWare Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/overview.html) installed in order to run the simulator VM.  This is mentioned in the [system requirements](http://developer.blackberry.com/develop/simulator/simulator_systemrequirements.html).  All the dmg installer does is uncompress the VMware image and place it on your hard drive.  I just installed this myself, and the default location seems to be:

`/Users/<your username>/Documents/Virtual Machines`

Inside there should be a folder `Blackberry10Simulator-BB10_1_X-338` and inside that there should be `BlackBerry10Simulator-BB10_1_X.vmwarevm` which contains the actual virtual machine .vmx and .vmdk files.

There should also be an alias (shortcut) created on your desktop to point to this location, called `Blackberry 10 Simulator`.

To uninstall, there is a script in `Blackberry10Simulator-BB10_1_X-338/install` called `uninstaller` which should remove everything and allow you to install again.

Unfortunately, VMWare Fusion is not free but you can sign up for a [30-day trial](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/evalcenter?p=vmware-fusion5) in order to be able to run the simulator and test out your app.

Comment: Thanks.I have VMware, but I cann't find anything with searching **.vmwarevm** in Finder on entire machine.   Maybe there is something wrong while first time installing.  Now I want to re-install the simulator, but it has the error, "Multiple launches of this installer is not allowed."  I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: @phenmod I just installed it myself and updated my answer with the default install locations, and the location of the uninstaller.

Comment: I can not find the folder "/Users/<your username>/Documents/Virtual Machines" .   Now I think I have not installed simulator successfully at the first time. 
 
When I double clicked BlackBerry10Simulator-Installer-BB10_1_X-338-Mac-201302031817.dmg,  there is no pop-up Finder window with the installer, but  just mounted.   I have to start BlackBerry10Simulator-Installer.app from Finder, and then the installer will report "Multiple launches of this installer is not allowed. It will now quit".
Did you need start the installer from Finder by yourself?

 i will try the uninstaller soon .

Comment: Found similar problem at: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Install-blackberry-playbook-simulator-on-Mac/td-p/1593023  , the same installer multiple not allowed to execute instances problem.

Comment: @phenmod yes, I had to start the BlackBerry10Simulator-Installer.app from finder myself after double clicking and mounting the image.  Is the installer maybe already running in the background?  Have you tried restarting your system?

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this error with a different installer (but also installanywhere based).  There seems to be a problem with the mirroring feature in VM Ware Fusion and the multiple install detection in Install anywhere.  If you disable mirroring, I suspect the "Multiple launches of this installer is not allowed." error will no longer occur.